# Is the usage of "subsequent" in "One or more subsequent EEGs were available for 21 patients." clear?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> A locally interpreted EEG report from the first week of life was available for 20/23 patients; 11 showed burst suppression, 11 showed dysmaturity and/or focal findings, and 1 was normal. One or more **subsequent** EEGs were available for 21 patients.

Is the usage of "subsequent" in the above sentence correct?

One of my friends told me that here the word "subsequent" is not correct, because you initially take EEG scan for 20 patients, you cannot take subsequent scans for 21 patients and it will mislead readers.

Comment: You should include what you _think_ the sentence that includes _subsequent_ means, and what you _want_ that sentence to mean. It might be helpful to respondents.

Comment: @Max (^) I am struggling to find out the OP's intention in "One or more subsequent EEGs were available for 21 patients"

Comment: Your friend misunderstood the text.  There is nothing inconsistent.  All 23 patients had an initial EEG, not 20.  Of those, 20 reports were available for the analysis described.  Some number of the 23 patients (possibly all, but at least 21), had one or more subsequent EEGs.  One or more of those subsequent EEGs were available for each of 21 of the patients.

Answer (score 1):

First the 23 EEGs are mentioned.

> A locally interpreted EEG report from the first week of life was available for **20/23** patients; **11** showed burst suppression, **11** showed dysmaturity and/or focal findings, and **1** was normal.

After those EEGs were studied, there were more [*subsequent*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/subsequent) EEGs (it doesn't say how many) for 21 patients. At the moment of these statements, they existed but weren't studied yet. So this activity will occur after the first study.

> *adjective*
>   occurring after; succeeding